# "Changing feature ID of feature 123 is not allowed" when saving a GeoPackage (.gpkg) layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geopackage

I have been editing making some attribute and geometry edits to a GeoPackage layer, and when I go to save the changes, I get the above error for 8 features. This error apparently prevents me from saving at all. It is likely that in using the tool "Modify Attributes of Selected Features Simultaneously", I accidentally typed something in the Feature ID field. My understanding is that Feature ID shouldn't really be edited by the user in most (any?) cases, so I'm kind of wondering why it's an option to edit that field. Mostly though, I just need to know if there is a way to fix it. I have tried to save frequently to prevent losing work, but at this point I have about an hour or two of work that I am unable to save. I have made peace with the fact that I will likely have to redo this work. Nevertheless, I'm hoping that at the very least I might be able to learn something about this issue, if I'm not able to fix it in this case. It's clear that there is something I'm not getting here. And if it isn't obvious, I'm a fairly new user to QGIS.

Comment: Can you select the features that generate the error and export those to a new shapefile or geopackage?  They are not the same, if export to one fails try the other.  if one works that will at least save that work.  Then you can delete them from your current working layer and hopefully save that.  Then you can address the issues in the first comment.

Comment: Hi @johns, Unfortunately I deleted the first comment just before you publish the second. In the comment I asked if they were trying to save non-unique ids.

Comment: I am not sure how to find the features that generate the error. When I look for the feature with the id of '123' for example, it is not listed in the attribute table, presumably because it has been changed to something else.

Comment: Each feature has its own id, so the message should change if the error occurs in 8 different features, showing the 8 ids with problems, in the [Log Messages Panel](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#log-messages-panel). Also, when you populate any field with the $id expression you are able to see the id of the feature, so you can know which feature has the 123 id. The field for ids in geopackage is named fid by default.

Comment: What QGIS version are you using?

Comment: I am on version 3.22.7

Comment: What happens if you remove the fid field, and still without saving the changes, export the layer to a new geopackage from the QGIS layers panel?

Comment: That solved the problem! Thank you!

Comment: If you make an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: I will edit my previous answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoPackage databases standard requires a field for tables (layers when instantiated in QGIS) to be registered as Feature ID field. By default, that field is called *fid*.

You can see what is the name of the Feature ID field in the *Information* tab of the layer properties. In the *Fields* section, it is shown as *Primary key attributes*.

That field is automatically filled in by an existing trigger in the database, and a different value than the one already assigned cannot be saved.

It is true that QGIS should not allow you to modify it in most cases. But there are other cases in which it is necessary to do so. For example, when a disaggregation process is carried out on an existing geopackage, and several resulting features bring the *fid* value of the same original feature.

In any case, it is a very specific constraint of the GeoPackage provider.

---

> I just need to know if there is a way to fix it.

Yes, once you are done making all the changes, populate the *fid* field with the `$id` expression and and you'll be able to save the changes.

Although this way has always worked for me, and I have rechecked that it still works, for some reason it may not have worked on your data.

In that case, there is the possibility of completely recreating the *fid* field, removing it from the original table and, still without saving the changes, exporting the layer to a new GeoPackage file.

There is also the possibility of exporting the layer without deleting the previous field, by selecting in the export dialog a new field to be taken as Feature ID instead of *fid*, so that the values written in the *fid* field are kept but the primary key constraint applies to a new field.

Comment: I followed your suggestion as best I could by opening the attribute table and then entering `$id` into the expression dialogue and evaluating for feature id. This changed the feature id for many of the features, so that seems like progress. Unfortunately I am still unable to save, due to the same error. Thank you for the suggestion, and I apologize if I misunderstood you. If it's not obvious yet, I have little experience with QGIS.

Comment: Hi, no problem. Is the feature id field named: "fid"? Are you sure that changes were not saved? Can you clear all error messages and try again, because when i do the same i can save the changes.

Comment: Also, my way to do that is through the [Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator), by selecting _Update existing field_ and selecting the _fid_ field in the list of fields. Also, don't select the _Only update the n selected features_ so all features are updated. In the expression tab use the $id expression and _OK_. But if you are writing the right features id field for all features with the _Quick Field Calculation Bar_ must work too.

Comment: The feature id field is shown as _Primary Key Attribute_ in the _Information_ tab of layer properties.

Comment: There are only two attributes in the file right now, fid, and a string attribute I'm editing. I checked the _Information_ tab as well to make sure. I wish I could say I've been working with the wrong attribute this whole time, but unfortunately I don't think that's the issue. Thank you for checking though.

Comment: These are all good things to double check. 
I also redid the calculation with the Field Calculator tool with no luck. And I have been clearing the error messages. The error messages reappear when I try to save. And the layer shows an orange pencil, I believe indicating unsaved changes. Thank you for your thoughts.

Answer (score -1):

I get like error when I while  merge 2 or more object . and usually  qgis gives such this error when qgis cant match fid (object id) values .for example if you select take attributes from with the longest lenght doesnt give such errors.

and another for example  when you use attribute painter  as much as possible dont tick object id and shape lenght etc( which can not to be changed features)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/251484)